# Does knowing the Identity ID compromise security?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am looking at a Unit Test project, which contains the following code:

```
public const string IDENTITY_ID = "9e326389-1ae6-4672-9dc4-7868ab7b7a09";

        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public AutoAuthorizeMiddleware(RequestDelegate rd)
        {
            _next = rd;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity("cookies");

            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", IDENTITY_ID));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("unique_name", IDENTITY_ID));

            httpContext.User.AddIdentity(identity);

            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
```

Please note that I have generated a random `Guid` for the question.

It appears that theunit test invokes the web api (inside the Invoke method) and is able to access a method, which has an Authorise attribute.

Does forumating an identity like this mean the user is authorised?

I am trying to learn more about how Identity Server works and hence the reason for the question.

Comment: ideally your claims should be cryptographically signed or some other securing mechanism coming from your client.

Comment: @Daniel A. White, thanks - that would help prevent a man in the middle attack.  However, what about a DBA who has access to the aspnetusers table in the database.  Does that mean the DBA can impersonate anyone?

Comment: @w0051977anyone with that level of access could overwrite the user's password and sign in as them easily yes - you'd need to lock down your user store as far as is practical. What you'd done in your example above is essentially what the cookie or bearer token authentication handler would do in an application but only after they'd authenticated the cookie or token!

Comment: @mackie, thanks.  So it is possible to break security if you know the Identity id of the user? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 it's possible to break security if it's already broken I guess. What you're doing here wouldn't be possible in a real application as the security context would only be established after authentication of some credentials, a token or a cookie sent with the request.

Comment: If a user can call `httpContext.User.AddIdentity(identity);` with whatever value they want then yes. But hopefully this shouldn't be the case.